# What was Josh wearing in Big (1988) right when he made his wish to be “big”?

Tags: big

While it became ill-fitting when he became an adult, he changed over night, not instantly, how did his clothes fit him then?

Comment: definitely the magic did not affect clothes size when he got young again. i forget the scene -- did he steal his dad's clothing? i recall i think really liking that film which had at least (no spoiler here, the joke is too good) one belly laugh (when his mom first sees the adult Josh).

Answer (score 2):

His own clothes didn't fit, so Josh stole his father's clothes. It's a little clearer in the [official novelisation](https://archive.org/details/big_20220614).

> Josh riffled through his father’s dresser drawers. He found a set of
> underwear he could fit into and some brown slacks his father wore on
> weekends, so he would not miss them today. From among the shirts, Josh
> selected a New York Giants T-shirt. His father didn’t have what
> would have been Josh’s first choice: a Yankees shirt. He grabbed
> some red socks from a drawer and an expensive pair of running shoes
> from the closet floor to complete his outfit. Satisfied, he gave
> Rachel back her teething ring and escaped back down the hall to his
> own room.
>
> A few moments later, Josh re-emerged. The brown pants hung loosely on
> his hips, threatening to slide down. He snuck back to his father’s
> closet to borrow a belt. Unable to find one, he grabbed a necktie from
> the rack in the closet and threaded it through the loops. The
> shirttails of the T-shirt covered most of the tie.

Comment: I think in  the initial "wake up" scene, "Big Josh" gets out of bed wearing underwear that already fits him, so that's an anomaly. It was remarked about on IMDB.

Comment: @Spencer - Underpants are pretty stretchy

Comment: You speak from experience?

Comment: @Spencer - Modesty forbids